# How to disable/restrict any and all music on my iPhone 5c?

Tags: iphone, music.app

I have an iPhone 5c and would like to restrict any and all music, including the music app in the restriction settings or just plain delete the radio all together.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible without jailbreaking. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html